# How to add Html input values into a PHP array?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a large amount of input fields. How can I pass the values into an array so I can pass the array from one page to another? 
example:

```
<input type="text" value=<?php $arry = "compName" ?> placeholder="Company Name"  />
```

Is this legal? How can I do this properly?

EDIT:

In my page, I have "add" and "delete" buttons that will add/delete more input fields. I also have a "preview" button at the bottom. User will add/delete before hitting preview. Preview will collect all input and will call the next page. So the amount of field is unknown.

Here's what my code/markup looks like:

```
<div class="panel" style="width: 98%; margin:0 auto">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-6 columns">
                Advertiser Info: <hr>
                <input type="text" value="compName" placeholder="Company Name"  />
                <input type="text" value= "adEmail" placeholder="Email"  />
                <input type="text" value="adContName" placeholder="Contact Name"  />
                <input type="text" value="adPhone" placeholder="Phone # (NO DASHES)"  />
                <input type="text" value="adStreet" placeholder="Street Address"  />
                <input type="text" value="adCity" placeholder="City"  />
                <input type="text" value="adState" placeholder="State/Provice"  />
                <input type="text" value="adZip" placeholder="Zip/Postal Code"  />
                <input type="text" value="adCountry" placeholder="Country"  />

            </div>

            <div class="large-6 columns">
                Billing Info: <hr>
                <input type="text" value="bEmail" placeholder="Email"  />
                <input type="text" value="bContName" placeholder="Contact Name"  />
                <input type="text" value="bPhone" placeholder="Phone # (NO DASHES)"  />
                <input type="text" value="bStreet" placeholder="Street Address"  />
                <input type="text" value="bCity" placeholder="City"  />
                <input type="text" value="bState" placeholder="State/Provice"  />
                <input type="text" value="bZip" placeholder="Zip/Postal Code"  />
                <input type="text" value="bCountry" placeholder="Country"  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So when the user hits add and EXACT copy of above code will be made.

With that said, I want to be able to use PHP arrays for html values to pass. How can I set my inputs so that I can do this?

Comment: If you didn't mind using Javascript / jQuery, serialize the form and fill into a hidden field during onsubmit().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do some tweaks like:

Using input type elements as array elements.

So that:

```
<input type="text" name="elem[name]" value="<?php echo $YOUR_VALUE;?>"
<input type="text" name="elem[class]" value="<?php echo $YOUR_VALUE;?>"
<input type="text" name="elem[marks]" value="<?php echo $YOUR_VALUE;?>"
```

So that the variables are you are posting should be less.

In this case, you are posting only one variable instead of three.

Comment: what if I had <input type="text" name="elem[name] value=<?php echo $var; ?> placeholder="Company Name"  /> TWICE, and I wanted them to be separate array elements?

Comment: You can use array keys to differentiate between elements. for example, in the above example, you still have three elements: name, class and marks.

Comment: let me edit my code/mark up in my post to give you a better understanding of what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to get all the values of input fields and make a json object of {input_name:value} or array variable of key value and then pass it in argument.

```
var key_value = {};
$('input').each(function(){
    key_value[$(this).attr('name')]= $(this).val();
})
alert(JSON.stringify(key_value));
```

Now you have an object with field name as key and its value.